# Little doubt about Cantor's proof that for any $S$, there isn't a bijection $S\to P(S)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm reading Crossley et al's What is Mathematical Logic? They give a proof that there is no bijection from $\Bbb{N}\to [0,1]$ and then, there is this:

> [image]

I'm trying to understand this: We're assuming there is a map $S\to \{T:T\subset S\}$. And then there is $U$ which has (I think) the following definition:

$$U=\{s\in S : f(s)=T_s \text{ and } s \notin T_s \}$$

And then they say $U$ can never be matched with an $s\in S$. It's not clear to me why is that. I think there are two cases:

- Suppose there is an $s\in S$ such that $s\to U$ and $s\in U$ but this is absurd because $U$ contains only elements which are not mapped to sets that contain them.
- Suppose there is an $s\in S$ such that $s\to U$ and $s\not\in U$... I think this should yield some kind of problem but I can't think what the problem is.

Or perhaps, the problem is something else? It's not clear at all why $U$ can't be mapped. Can you help me? I understand the proof I mentioned in the beginning of the question but this proof, which according to the text is similar to it, always eluded me.

Also, another question that is bugging me a lot: How do we know that $U$ isn't empty?

Comment: if $s \mapsto U$ and $s \notin U$, then actually $s$ must be in $U$, because $s \notin f(s)$

Comment: @jacob [YES! THAT'S IT! I FINALLY UNDERSTAND IT!](https://youtu.be/uwmeH6Rnj2E)

Comment: I'm almost certain that this question is a duplicate in that Cantor's diagonal arguments have been thoroughly dissected on the site. Check out the list of related questions in the right margin and search for more. Anyway, to answer your last question (=something I'm not sure we have covered earlier!). We don't care! If $U$ should be empty, it simply means that the empty set is not in the image of $f$ (again proving that $f$ is not surjective).

Comment: Are $f(s)$ and $T_s$ different notations for the same thing here?

Comment: Maybe $U$ **is** $\emptyset$, that’s not a problem. The range of any such $f$ will omit some subsets of $S$ and they don’t have to be exotic. In fact, if $f(x) = \{x\}$ then actually $U=\emptyset$. Your definition of $U$ is correct, Crossley’s reads like an enthusiastic and excellent science writer but it’s wholly accurate. That’s a great little book!

Comment: @C7X Yes, they are.